# Can't register with SIP account (opensips server)

Tags: android, sip, linphone, opensips

I am trying to build an Android application that uses linphone to make calls, using OpenSips for SIP registration.

I've successfully installed OpenSIPs in Ubuntu server,and created account in it, but can't register with this account. Got `(Registration on sip:xx.xx.xx.xx failed:timeout)`

I'm a complete beginner in SIP and opensips,so I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong!

Any help would be appreciated,

Best regards,

Manar

Comment: What is the code that gives you this error?

Comment: At first, I'm just testing with linphone app ! also tried with X-lite but it's not working too ...

Comment: opensips provides a command line interface for management. Find the right command line to make sure that your user actually exists.
Then, use a network traffic capture tool like wireshark to make sure your packets are going to the right interface, ip address, etc. Also check on which ip address opensips is listening. Check ipv4 vs ipv6, etc.

Answer (score 0):

@yohann.martineau Thanks for your reply ! Actually i Resolved my problem...

I was editing the residential scripte : setting opensips to listen on a public IP. My error is that i was giving just the public IP  like this : listen=udp :xx.xx.xx.xx:5060  when the correct syntax is giving both public and private IP

==> listen=udp:127.0.0.1:5060 as xx.xx.xx.xx:5060